# Creating a parameter that accepts input for an array

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I am practicing making arrays. I have created two classes. The first class (Processor class) contains a parameter that accepts an array of 10 values that the user inputs. It also contains 4 methods to process: the average of the numbers entered, the largest value, the smallest value, and a toString method. This class compiles with no errors.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Processor {
    public int[] value;
    int aSum = 0;
    int largest = value[0];
    int smallest = value[0];
    private int number;

    public Processor() {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
    }

    public void arrayAverage(int[] value) {
        double average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            aSum = aSum + value[i];
            average = aSum / value.length;
        }
    }

    public void arrayMax() {
        for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] > largest) {
                largest = value[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public void arrayMin() {
        for (int i = 1; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = value[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.toString(value);
    }
}
```

The second class `ProcessorTester` creates an instance of Processor and asks for the user to input 10 values for the array. I then call the methods from the first class and print their values. However, when I compile this class I get the following error: "`incompatible type- int cannot be converted to Processor`".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProcessorTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Processor[] inputs = new Processor[10];
        System.out.println("Input 10 values for the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();


        }
        System.out.println("The average of the numbers inputed is: ");
        System.out.println(arrayAverage.inputs());
        System.out.println("The largest of the numbers inputed is: ");
        System.out.println(arrayMax.inputs());
        System.out.println("The smallest of the numbers inputed is: ");
        System.out.println(arrayMin.inputs());
        System.out.println("The numbers inputed are: ");
        System.out.println(toString.inputs());
    }
}
```

Is this a problem with my coding in the main method in the `Processor` class?

Comment: Please for your sake and ours, try to make your indentations better. Either let your IDE do your code indentations for you (most have a format code command), or learn the standard rules of code indentation and follow them. This will make it much easier for us to follow your code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its very straightforward. You are trying to assign an int value to a Program variable

Answer (score 0):

You've declared inputs as an array of `Processor`:

```
Processor[] inputs = new Processor[10];
```

A `Processor` contains an array of integer, but a `Processor` is not an integer. Thus, this isn't legal:

```
inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
```

that says to take the ith `Processor` and assign it an integer. But `inputs[i]` is a `Processor` so you can only assign `Processor` to it.

Pro-tip: when the compiler gives you an error, it will tell which line in which file caused the error. When posting a question always indicate the line that causes the compile error as that saves people from having to read every line of your file trying to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Code here:

```
Processor[] inputs=new Processor[10];  //1

for(int i=0; i<inputs.length;i++)
{
    inputs[i]=keyboard.nextInt();   //2
}
```

`//1` You make an array of type `Processor`
`//2` You try to fill this Array with integers `inputs[i]=keyboard.nextInt();`

This causes this specific error.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend the following changes at the least:

**Processor class**

Change

```
public Processor() {
    int[] numbers = new int[10];
}
```

to

```
public Processor() {
    value = new int[10];
}
```

**ProessorTest Class**

In the main method,

change

```
    Processor[] inputs = new Processor[10];
    System.out.println("Input 10 values for the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i] = keyboard.nextInt();


    }
```

to

```
    Processor inputs = new Processor();
    System.out.println("Input 10 values for the array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs.value.add(keyboard.nextInt());
    }
```